# Creating 2D struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have aproblem with this code, it compiles ok. But it crashes imidiately after memory could not be written error.

Debugger says the problem is in the line *grid = (grid_t**)malloc(sizeof(grid_t)*GRID_HEIGHT); , i must be missing something obvious.

I'm trying to create a pointer to a 2D struct.

```
#define GRID_WIDTH 12
#define GRID_HEIGHT 22

typedef struct
{
    int piece;
    int edge;
}grid_t;

grid_t*** grid;

*grid = (grid_t**)malloc(sizeof(grid_t)*GRID_HEIGHT);

for(int i = 0 ; i < GRID_HEIGHT ; i++)
{
    *grid[i] = (grid_t*)malloc(sizeof(grid_t)*GRID_WIDTH);
}
```

Comment: Well you dereference `grid` (i.e.: `*grid = ...`) which is an unallocated pointer (with the above code anyway).

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: Wellcome to SO. This is not a code review site, please ask a concrete technical question.

Answer (score 4):

You dereference an unallocated pointer:

```
grid_t*** grid;
*grid = (grid_t**)malloc(sizeof(grid_t)*GRID_HEIGHT);
```

`grid` is not allocated when you do `*grid`, so it's undefined behavior.

If you want to dynamically allocate two-dimensional structs, you first need to allocate enough memory for pointers (`grid_t*`) in the first level:

```
grid_t** grid;
grid = malloc(sizeof(*grid) * GRID_HEIGHT);
```

Then you can allocate each element with a loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < GRID_HEIGHT ; i++)
{
    grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(**grid) * GRID_WIDTH);
    // ...then you can do grid[i]->piece = 42; etc..
}
```

Now, from what I can see, you probably don't even need dynamic allocation. If you don't need `malloc`, don't use it, just use good ol' arrays instead:

```
grid_t grid[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];
```

Comment: Tnx, now how can i get a pointer to grid?

Comment: @dexter313: Use the addressof operator (`&`)?

Comment: @dexter313 `grid` **is** a pointer. If there is some reason you need the *address* of that pointer (or any variable in C) you can use `&grid`. It is not evidently clear why you have such a need, but that is how.